# Unique Constraint Violation in Camunda

Tags: unique-constraint, camunda

we are using Camunda, currently version 7.0.0, but right now in the process of upgrading to version 7.3.

We recently had the first real multi-using test with camunda and it was cut short within minutes by a unique constraint violation with a clash being detected on the primary key of act_hi_comment.

Is this a bug of camunda or did we do something wrong?

Comment: Which id generator do you use?

Comment: Do you do 7.0->7.3 in one step or do you migrate to intermediate version?

Comment: @thorben we did not define a specific generator, so, camunda-default.

Comment: @JanGalinski we do the update in one step

Comment: Do you use a shared or embedded engine? If shared, how do you bootstrap the engine (i.e. programmatically or via bpm-platform.xml/standalone.xml)? Edit: make sure you use the StrongUuidGenerator. It is set by default for shared engines declared in bpm-platform.xml but not for embedded engines. There you'll have to set it via the configuration property `idGenerator`.

Comment: @thorben we use the engine embedded. I'll check about the StrongUuidGenerator.

Comment: @thorben I just checked: we already use the StrongUuidGenerator. Any further Ideas?

Comment: Hm, not sure. You could post the exception message and the stacktrace. You could try to reproduce the issue in a unit test environment and post it to the camunda forums (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/camunda-bpm-users). And last option would be debugging. Perhaps you can determine whether two independent engines submit a comment with the same id or whether an engine tries to INSERT a second time an existing comment instead of making an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Do you have any custom code in place to update an existing comment?

Comment: Agree with Thorben. StrongUuidGenerator is a must in any production environment. I believe this is the default for version 7.2 and beyond, but may not have been so in 7.0.

Comment: @GregHarley-BP3: I agree, yet, it is important to use one which actually works. The 3.1.0 (shipped with camunda 7.0) doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `com.fasterxml.uuid.impl.TimeBasedGenerator` in Version 3.1.0 has a severe multi-threading issue. It uses a global, non-synchronized byte-array for construction of the uuid, so multiple simultaneous calls from different threads will always generate the same id. This problem is easily reproducable.

This issue has been fixed in 3.1.1 and beyond (so camunda 7.3 will most probably not be affected). For our legacy-installations with camunda 7.0.0 we are now using a wrapper around the StringUuidGenerator, which synchronizes the `getNextId` method.